# Does inline styling effects a react app load time (FCP, LCP)?

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

Does inline styling effects a react app load time (FCP, LCP)?
How does it differ from styling in a css file?

Answer (score 0):

Inline styling shouldn't affect react app load time. Furthermore, if there is a chance it affects it, it should lower the time of app render. Anyway, its not recommended to do inline styling, as it makes ur code messy. There are certain cases that u can use inline styling with one rule, but generally its much better to use classes defined in css file

Comment: How do you know it doesn't affect load time ??? Any explanation my friend. It is not the inline style of HTML, we are talking about JSX dear :) And this is all Javascript being used to style actually

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to inline style within a React component we know it basically is JSX that we are talking about and styling that happens in inline is basically passing an Object to the `style` prop. Internally ReactDOM takes care of all this.

And DOM styling is managed hence forth. It does differ from loading from CSS file in the same way that you can style in Javascript using imperative approach.

Now coming to the question whether it impacts load speed and you have used (FCP,LCP) in the Bracket.Actually LCP is actually considered only for few elements.

Learn more from https://web.dev/lcp/

> Overall I believe, it depends how many style properties are used
> inline. And still I believe, It actually increases the load time and
> does not decrease it in case of React (because Javascript is involved
> not direct CSS file [hence additional work]) for ReactDOM.

Comment: And I can be wrong in the way I have answered as well, Then I would happily like someone to correct me. But as far as the Gut feeling goes and my experience with React so far goes, I think it will increase the load time and not decrease it